# How do I disable all the popups on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, popups

How do I disable all the popups appearing on the top of Stack Exchange sites?
It's those bars saying stuff like: You've earned "Student" and 1 other badge. See your profile.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hide popups
// @include       http://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://*superuser.com/*
// @include       http://*serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://*stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include       http://*askubuntu.com/*
// @version       1.0
// @namespace     hide popups
// ==/UserScript==
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.textContent = "#notify--1 { visibility: hidden !important; }";
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

I think this adblock filter doesn't work:
    meta.stackoverflow.com##[id*="notify-"]

Comment: How about Stylish or AdBlock? Also, define `Popup`.

Comment: note that once you earn 100+ rep many of these (simple bronze badges mostly) are suppressed network wide.

Comment: These are more accurately notifications, generally it's only called a pop up if it opens another window

Comment: I thought these were [toasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(computing)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### User Script

I have just received a notification message, and constructed a script that *visually* hides these messages. At the top of the script, I have also added code to mark the message as read.

The code utilises jQuery, which is embedded on each page at the Stack Exchange.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hide notification messages
// @description   Hide notification messages at the Stack Exchange network
// @match         http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         http://superuser.com/*
// @match         http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match         http://serverfault.com/*
// @match         http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match         http://askubuntu.com/*
// @match         http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match         http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match         http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match         http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match         http://stackapps.com/*
// @version       3.0
// @namespace     Rob W
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
if ($) {
    // This part will mark the message as read
    $("a[href*=mark-as-read]").each(function(){
        $.ajax(this.href);
    });

    // Remove the notification message
    $("#notify-container").hide().closest('body').css('marginTop',0);
}
```

#### User Style (Stylish)

The [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension is more useful for this purpose. Create a new User Style, and add the following code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"),
               domain("superuser.com"),
               domain("serverfault.com"),
               domain("stackapps.com"),
               domain("stackexchange.com"),
               domain("askubuntu.com"),
               domain("answers.onstartups.com") {
  body {
      margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  #notify-container {
      display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: They both don't work. They might be working on some other of my firefox installations, but on these few they don't. Have you tested it?

Comment: @nnn Thanks for the notice. I've updated and tested both versions, they work now.

Comment: You may want to post this script on GitHub Gist and add a StackApps page for it ([see this comment thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content/132142#comment365279_132142) ). This way users can one-click install.