# As a 10k user, how do I ignore deleted answers?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I just became a 10k user over at maths.SE, and now I see deleted answers, but I don't want to see them. (They're distracting.)

How do I ignore deleted answers?
If there's not already a non-contrived way of achieving this, would it be possible to add a "[.] hide deleted answers" switch in the prefs tab (or something similar)?

Comment: Give out some 500 rep bounties... =D

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content

Comment: How exactly are they distracting? They are at the bottom anyway.

Comment: @Bart: They are only at the bottom if you sort by votes.

Comment: @juergend Ah, that explains it. I only sort by votes.

Comment: 10K tools are not relevant and it's pure feature request, retagging accordingly.

Comment: @J.Steen you joke, but I actually [asked about that before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/has-anyone-out-there-tried-to-stop-gaining-rep-so-as-to-not-surpass-10k).

Comment: @PopularDemand Actually, I wasn't joking completely. If you have no real interest in partaking of the 10k duties, you should - and, ah, yes. As that question already states. =)

Comment: There's something inelegant about the "give away rep" solution (and similarly for the "start another account" solution); hence the "non-contrived".  Also, I like to be able to change my mind in the future.  How is it distracting?  There are people I know professionally on maths.SE and don't want to see their bloopers.  I guess it is a duplicate; I added an answer to the meta.maths.SE Q citing this one.

Comment: Bottom-line: you shouldn't be asking "how are they distracting?"; you should be asking "How are deleted answers relevant?". A person that doesn't want to see deleted answers, but also wants to continue growing their rep (because it's a function of their own personal growth) should have an option to not show deleted posts. Give away rep as the solution, is a pretty lousy solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way to ignore deleted answers with a preference.

You could set `div.deleted-answer: { display: none }` in a custom stylesheet instead.

There are Stylish plugins for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), [Safari](http://sobolev.us/stylish/) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/stylish-for-opera/); use one of those to manage such a custom stylesheet.

Alternatively, install the [Deleted Answer Manager user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3408/stack-overflow-deleted-answer-manager).

Comment: Does the Deleted Answer Manager work for maths.SE?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: You'll have to customize the sites for which it is run. By default it only runs on Stack Overflow (`// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/*`). How you do that differs from browser to browser.

Comment: Thanks I got the Deleted Answer Manager to work in Chrome via Tampermonkey on maths.SE by editing that line in the script.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: The Tampermonkey extension also lets you add includes on the 'Settings' tab for the script. Go to the Tampermonkey settings, click on the script in question, and then select the 'Settings' tab. That way you get to keep your additional sites when the script is updated in the future.